# Which of the graphs are isomorphic (GRE math subject test)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Could you guys take a look at the following two screenshots? I believe I, II, and III are all isomorphic to each other, while the answer only gives I and III.

For II, consider mapping ABCD to EGFH, through which, I believe, it gives both a bijection of vertices while preserving their adjacencies.

Can someone confirm me that the answer is incorrect, or can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd3xe.png)
[answer to this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sFMu.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures. This concerns only your first picture.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with you. The only way you'd be wrong is if there is something unusual with the way the second graph is supposed to be interpreted visually. If the only links that exist are indeed (EG), (GF) and (FH) then it should be indeed isomorphic. And clearly whoever made the answer was being careless, judging by the notation of the bijection $g$.

Comment: The bijection specified in the answer may not work but $ABCD\to EGFH$ seems to work.

Comment: It seems whoever wrote the answer had confused themselves into thinking only about *order preserving* bijections, but of course there is no requirement that such a bijection be order preserving, only adjacency preserving.  They gave an example of a bijection which was not adjacency preserving, which by itself does not prove that there are *no* adjacency preserving bijections.  All you need is at least one adjacency preserving bijection.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! I am preparing for the GRE math subject test. However, I am an undergraduate statistics major, and there are lots of concepts I haven't learnt. To make matters worse, there seems to be quite a few typos and wrong answers in the book, which makes me even more confusing. I may need some helps from your guys to fight me through these tricky concepts and wrong answers during these test-preparation days. Thanks again!